# How do I prevent gaps in SSRS elements due to expanding matrix?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a report with three charts, and underneath them a matrix. The matrix expands horizontally at run time, leaving a big horizontal gap between the first and second chart. How do I fix this?

In HTML I'd just throw a <br clear="all"/> in there to ensure that the matrix isn't affecting the formatting of other elements.

Horrible mspaint graphic below:
http://www.paulw.us/blog/uploads/ssrs-gap.PNG

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a rectangle to wrap the charts.

I've had similar issues and found that providing an extra "layer" (can't think of better word) makes the renderer separate controls reliably.